# How to generate classes.dex.toc files?

Tags: java, android

Here is the make file i am using to generate and JAVA module which i am importing in another module. While compiling it, the build breaks saying

```
error: 'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.hardware.automotive.vehicle@2.0-java_intermediates/classes.dex.toc', needed by 'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/vendor.harman.hardware.automotive.vehicle.fca_r1@1.0-java_intermediates/with-local/classes.dex', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Any suggestion on how to generate a .toc file in general?
Anything specific to be added in the make file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually such toc file will be auto generated during fullbuild, but if it is missing when you build single module you can manually generate the classes.dex.toc with the following command:

```
dexdump2 classes.dex >> classes.dex.toc
```

If you want to know the details, please read the sourcecode of android build system: `_transform_dex-to-toc`
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/f972a4a980660d2347ace8fdc7c668403c0e9697/core/definitions.mk